# Limit the terminal access to root user in debian

Tags: linux, root, console

A simple question, I've been looking everywhere and I couldn' find the answer : How can I limit my root account in Debian ? I need that the root have access only to one connection at a time in the terminal.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: This has an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) feel about it.  What problem are you actually trying to solve, here?

Comment: Even if you can configure this, you are aware that the root user has the rights to remove these restrictions, right?

Answer (score 1):

#### Allowed user on ssh

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
AllowUsers root@{serverIP}
```

#### Limit ssh connexion to 1

Edit `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
root    hard    maxlogins    1
```

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't formulate well my question, I need to limit to 1 the access to my local console, not SSH.

Thank you all

Comment: maybe you should remove the ssh tag then ?

Comment: This is useless, as the root user is able to remove the restrictions.

Comment: @Gerald not totaly, if one root is logged then another can't login to make the changes. Anyway even if it is useless it stay a question ? else close it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only one `root` session in one time, you will have to implement some kind of reject script to be run after authentication. For this, the `ForceCommand` option in `sshd_config` is really useful.

The script can looks basically somehow like this:

```
ForceCommand users | grep root || $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

If ssh is not the concern, then you can put something like this into your `.bashrc` or `.profile`:

```
users | grep root && exit
```

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't formulate well my question, I need to limit to 1 the access to my local console, not SSH.

Thank you all

Comment: so putting something similar into `.profile` or `.bashrc` should do the same.

Comment: This is useless, as the root user is able to remove the restrictions.